# Why won't the fourth character move when the left or right arrow keys are pressed?

Tags: python, pygame

The fourth MOLINE or character does not move when the left or right arrow keys are pressed. I cannot see any error in the code. So my question is, what is my issue?

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

BLACK =          (  0,   0,   0)
ABINO =          ( 34,  45, 102)
PINDLER =        (255, 123,  90)
MEXON =        (200, 200, 200)

size = [700, 500]
D = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Tester of Mester")

def MOLINE1(D, x, y):
    pygame.draw.ellipse(D, BLACK, [1 + x, y, 10, 10], 0)

    pygame.draw.line(D, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [10 + x, 27 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(D, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [x, 27 + y], 2)

    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 17 + y], [5 + x, 7 + y], 2)

    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 7 + y], [9 + x, 17 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 7 + y], [1 + x, 17 + y], 2)

def MOLINE2(D, x, y):
    pygame.draw.ellipse(D, BLACK, [1 + x, y, 10, 10], 0)

    pygame.draw.line(D, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [10 + x, 27 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(D, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [x, 27 + y], 2)

    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 17 + y], [5 + x, 7 + y], 2)

    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 7 + y], [9 + x, 17 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 7 + y], [1 + x, 17 + y], 2)

def MOLINE3(D, x, y):
    pygame.draw.ellipse(D, BLACK, [1 + x, y, 10, 10], 0)

    pygame.draw.line(D, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [10 + x, 27 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(D, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [x, 27 + y], 2)

    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 17 + y], [5 + x, 7 + y], 2)

    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 7 + y], [9 + x, 17 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 7 + y], [1 + x, 17 + y], 2)

def MOLINE4(D, x, y):
    pygame.draw.ellipse(D, BLACK, [1 + x, y, 10, 10], 0)

    pygame.draw.line(D, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [10 + x, 27 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(D, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [x, 27 + y], 2)

    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 17 + y], [5 + x, 7 + y], 2)

    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 7 + y], [9 + x, 17 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 7 + y], [1 + x, 17 + y], 2)


x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0

x2_speed = 0
y2_speed = 0

x3_speed = 0
y3_speed = 0

x4_speed = 0
y4_speed = 0

x_coord = 300
y_coord = 300

x2_coord = 300
y2_coord = 300

x3_coord = 300
y3_coord = 300

x4_coord = 300
y4_coord = 300

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_speed =- 3
                x2_speed = 3
                y3_speed =- 3
                y4_speed = 3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_speed = 3
                x2_speed =- 3
                y3_speed = 3
                y4_speed =- 3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_speed =- 3
                y2_speed = 3
                x3_speed =- 3
                x4_speed = 3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_speed = 3
                y2_speed =- 3
                x3_speed = 3
                x4_speed =- 3

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_speed=0
                x2_speed=0
                y3_speed=0
                y4_speed=0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_speed=0
                x2_speed=0
                y3_speed=0
                y4_speed=0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_speed=0
                y2_speed=0
                x3_speed=0
                x4_speed=0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_speed=0
                y2_speed=0
                x3_speed=0
                x4_speed=0

    x_coord = x_coord + x_speed
    y_coord = y_coord + y_speed

    x2_coord = x2_coord + x2_speed
    y2_coord = y2_coord + y2_speed

    x3_coord = x3_coord + x3_speed
    y3_coord = y3_coord + y3_speed

    x4_coord = x4_coord + x4_speed
    y4_coord = x4_coord + x4_speed

    D.fill(MEXON)

    MOLINE1(D, x_coord, y_coord)

    MOLINE2(D, x2_coord, y2_coord)

    MOLINE3(D, x3_coord, y3_coord)

    MOLINE4(D, x4_coord, y4_coord)


    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

As you can probably see, it should work fine as the code looks just like the previous three MOLINE characters and yet here we are. I am stumped. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning player 4's new position wrong.

```
    x4_coord = x4_coord + x4_speed
    y4_coord = x4_coord + x4_speed
```

This should be

```
    x4_coord = x4_coord + x4_speed
    y4_coord = y4_coord + y4_speed
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks much! This was was my issue. I can't believe my eyes passed over that the bazillions of times I proofread the code. Glad I came here!